# System sound effect for copy, paste and delete operations

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, audio, copy-paste, finder

Does anyone know how to play the system sound effects for (drag) copy, paste and delete operations on OS X? I mean the sound that Finder uses when moving files. I didn't find any API to do that. Does someone maybe know where those sound files are located? I only found the system alert sounds (Frog, Submarine etc..).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SystemSounds` are available in

`/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/Resources/SystemSounds/`  location.

```
NSSound *systemSound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/Resources/SystemSounds/finder/move\ to\ trash.aif" byReference:YES];
if (systemSound) {
    [systemSound play];
}  

/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/Resources/CoreAudioAUUI.bundle/Contents/Resources
```

Comment: I don't have a SystemSounds folder or a CoreAudioAUII bundle in `/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/Resources/`. Just a lot of .lproj folders with strings and a couple of other files. Are you using Lion?

Comment: I found them in `/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds`. Thanks!

Comment: Just a note: you don't need the if statement to check that systemSound isn't nil, because in this case the method isn't even executed.